# Low-budget scifi movie: humans at war with mind-controlling aliens crash-land on jungle planet with crystal growths

Tags: story-identification

I think this movie came out in the early to mid '00s. Pretty sure it's not newer than 2008: I think I saw it around that time. I later forgot the title, and I've been unsuccessful finding it again by Googling for plot keywords.

I think it's a really good film, so I'm putting the spoilery bits I remember in spoiler tags.

The movie opens with a military team of humans who've crash-landed on an alien planet. The backstory is explained that humans are at war with a race of mind-controlling aliens who have been almost wiped out, except on this one last planet, and this team was sent to finish the job. The captain of their mission team was killed in the crash, and the rest have to make do to complete their mission. As they explore the mostly jungle planet they keep seeing these crystal (as I remember it) growths around and have these strange hallucinations because of the aliens' mind control.

> The humans are actually under the mind control influence of the aliens the entire time. The crystals on this planet partially block the telepathy which is why everyone's suffering from hallucinations: they're real memories creeping through. It turns out the human-alien war was lost long ago and this planet has the last holdouts of the free *human* population, and the team was sent to try to kill them off. At the end, they encounter the clone of their old captain as one of the residents of the human colony, and one of the aliens telepathically admits what's going on.

Comment: What nationality was the film?

Comment: I appeared to be American judging by the language and accents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be the movie *[Homeworld](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1230538/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt)* from 2008.

[Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/homeworld/) has the following plot summary which matches a lot of your description:

> A team of brave soldiers journey into the deepest reaches of outer space on a mission to unleash a virus that will devastate the alien species that seeks to wipe out all of humanity in director Phillip Hudson's low-budget sci-fi thriller. The year is 3037. A race of aliens with powerful psychic abilities is determined to make mankind a distant memory. In a last ditch effort to combat the otherworldly menace, a military strike team is dispatched to the alien's home planet armed with a powerful virus that's been engineered to directly attack the immune system of the hostile alien foe. Should the mission prove a success, the alien race will be exterminated and the threat to humanity neutralized. When the team crash lands on the alien planet and the captain suffers critical injuries, however, it's up to the inexperienced Lieutenant Gray to take control of the mission and deliver the payload. But this Homeworld harbors a deadly secret that leaves the soldiers unable to distinguish truth from illusion, a fact that could prove fatal for the entire human species.

In addition, the [official trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlfsPRkZyUQ) shows that the movie takes place in a jungle/wooded environment and at 1:09 and 1:38 you can see some green crystal growths.

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you!